# A question about Mazur separation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Geometric Hahn Banach Theorem which is also known as Mazur separation Theorem states that

Let $M$ be a vector subspace of the topological vector space $X.$ Suppose $K$ is a non-empty convex open subset of $X$ with $K \cap M = \emptyset.$ Then there is a closed hyperplane (codimension-1 vector subspace) $N\subseteq X$ that contains $M,$ but remains disjoint from $K$.

From this can we say the following:

Let $M$ be a closed subspace of a Banach space and let $K$ be a convex weakly compact subset of $X$ with $K\cap M=\emptyset$. Then there exists a continuous linear functional $f$ such that $M\subseteq \ker f$ and $\ker f \cap K=\emptyset$.

**My Reasoning**

Note that $X$ equipped with weak topology is a locally convex topological vector space. Since $M$ is strongly closed and convex, it is weakly closed. Also, $K$ is weakly compact and disjoint from $M.$ So we can find a weak convex neighborhood $V$ of $\theta$ such that $(M+V) \cap (K+V)=\emptyset$. Since $K$ is convex, $(K+V)$ will be *open* convex. In particular, $M\cap (K+V)=\emptyset$. Then by the above Theorem, we can find a closed hyperplane $H$ such that $M \subseteq H$ and $H\cap (K+V)=\emptyset.$ Construct $f:X\to \mathbb{K}$ ($\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R} ~or~ \mathbb{C}$) such that $\ker f=H$ (We can do it since $H$ is of codimension $1$). Since $H$ is weakly closed, it is strongly closed too. Therefore, $f\in X^*$ and $M\subseteq \ker f$, $\ker f \cap K=\emptyset$.

Is it okay? or I am missing anything?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit** Since I do not get any answer regarding this. I am attaching an edit. The first thing I used here is a convex and strongly closed set is weakly closed. Further I used a fact from linear algebra that any subspace of codimension $1$ associates to a linear functional. Am I correct? or anything missed?

Comment: seems ok at first sight.

Comment: Thankyou for your comment @supinf. Please help me regarding this, if there is any problem.

Comment: What is your question?  If you're asking for someone to check your proof you should add the proof-verification tag and state what you want at the start of your post.  As it stands, supinf appears to have answered your question -- but then you've asked another question that does little more than link to this and say this is your real question

Comment: I have added the proof in the reasoning and will be happy if some check my proof.@postmortes

Comment: I agree with supinf; there's nothing wrong with this.  You might clarify that you're treating $\theta$ as the $0$ element of your vector space since that's not a universal notation, but that's a tiny complaint.

Comment: @postmortes Thankyou for your comment